# How to plot date-hour on x-as in R?

Tags: r, datetime, plot

I am struggling with plotting a time series in R. I have regular discharge data. Each 15 minutes a new observation is recorded. So my data is in the form of a date and a time stamp (hour and minutes). 
I just want to plot the evolution of the discharge data in time. On the x-axis I want to have the time in day and month. But of course the observations need to be plotted according to their date (day-month-year) and time (hours and minutes).

I found ggplot, strptime, POSIXct, as.DATE and so on to use, but I can't see the forest for the trees... (I am quite new in R)

example:

`discharge  dateandtime
5,8152616   1/03/2020 0:00
5,6835847   1/03/2020 6:30
5,5535848   1/03/2020 13:00
5,5535789   1/03/2020 19:30
5,6835847   2/03/2020 0:00
5,4250033   2/03/2020 6:30
5,8152616   2/03/2020 13:00
5,6835847   2/03/2020 19:30
5,5535855   3/03/2020 0:00
5,5535855   3/03/2020 6:30
5,6835847   3/03/2020 13:00`

So far I've got this:

`testdata <-read.table("testdischargedata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec=",")
dateandtime <- as.POSIXct(testdata$dateandtime, format= "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") 
plot(dateandtime,testdata$discharge, type = "p")`

And then this is the plot: [First plot attempt, x axis mentions the written days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB6tK.png)

The x-asis mentions the days written (so mon, tue etc)...

And then if I use this code for plotting:

`plot(testdata$dateandtime, testdata$discharge, type = "p")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=testdata$dateandtime, labels=format(testdata$dateandtime, "%d/%m")`

Then I got this plot: [Second plot attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdMr5.png)

So the x-axis is now better, it mentiones the date and hour, but I only want the day and month. And also the observations are plotted in a weird way.

How can I improve this code? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello Lies, welcome to SO. Could you share what you have tried so far? We need to see how you set up the plot so that we can help you out.

Comment: @Jan , I edit my question and added that I have got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need? You were actually quite close. I did not have to change much. I noticed that you do not assign the result of the POSIX coercion to the data frame. When you use `testdata$dateandtime`  later in `axis.POSIX` the format is still wrong.

Next thing you have to do is to suppress plotting of the x-axis in the `plot` command. If not, you get two sets of axis labels. In the second command you add the axis the way you want it.

```
testdata <-read.table("testdischargedata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec=",")
testdata$dateandtime <- as.POSIXct(testdata$dateandtime, format= "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") 
plot(testdata$dateandtime, testdata$discharge, type = "p", xlab="Day", xaxt = "n")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=testdata$dateandtime, labels=format(testdata$dateandtime, "%d/%m"))
```

Comment: Ok many thanks! This already helps a lot! But is there a way to avoid that for every observation the day is added? So now the day is mentioned 4 times (four observations per day). How can I adapt that? It would be nice to have just four observations per day and so that only the day is mentioned.

Comment: I found somehting to show only the day and month on the x-axis, by using a sequence in the axis.POSIXct function, and then by day of course. 


`plot(datamaart$dateandtime, datamaart$discharge, type = "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Discharge (l/s)", col="red")
r <- as.POSIXct(round(range(datamaart$dateandtime), "hours"))
axis.POSIXct(1,at=seq(r[1], r[30], by = "day"), format = "%d %b")
`

But there is something I am doing wrong, because after this code a got the error message:

`Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number`

Can you help me out?

Comment: Check `r`. It has only two values. As a consequence `r[30]`returns `NA`. If you use `axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(r[1], r[2], by = "day"), format = "%d %b")` then I believe that is what you want, right?